# Alternate to use LIMIT in subquery in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, query, subquery, limits

I have 2 tables, `Resource` and `views` and I'm trying to get the list of all the items from **`Resource`** table whose `ran_resId` don't match with the `ran_resId` of last 2 records of **`views`** table. I'm trying to use `LIMIT` in my sub-query which is giving this error:

> This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Here's my query -

```
select r.res_id, r.res_name
from Resource AS r
where r.ran_resId NOT IN 
      ( select v.ran_resId
        from views AS v
        order by v.viewsid
        limit 2
      )
group by r.ran_resId
```

I've google it and found out that **LIMIT** can't be use in SubQuery in MySql, And as an alternate I could use **JOIN** however I'm not able to create the query to get the desired results. 
A help is highly appreciated.
**PS - I'm using MySql 5.6**

[image]

Comment: 1) Convert subquery to view. 2) Limit without ordering by unique field/expression gives random records, not last ones.

Comment: I'm using order-by as well in my subquery , I've updated the question thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: It would be much better if you provided the tables' data as text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

If `2` is a fixed value and you'll never need to compare against 3, 4 or more items in the future, then you could convert the subquery to a derived table and find the 2 values with aggregation:

```
select r.res_id, r.res_name
from Resource as r
     join
     ( select min(lim.ran_resid) as ran_resid_1,
              max(lim.ran_resid) as ran_resid_2 
       from
         ( select v.ran_resid
           from views as v
           order by v.viewsid
           limit 2
         ) as lim
     ) as x
     on r.ran_resid NOT IN (x.ran_resid_1, x.ran_resid_2)
 ;
```

A more general solution (where you can use any `LIMIT` and not just 2), is to write the antijoin with the `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` method:

```
select r.res_id, r.res_name
from Resource as r
     left join
     ( select v.ran_resid
       from views as v
       order by v.viewsid
       limit 5
     ) as x
     on r.ran_resid = x.ran_resid
where x.ran_resid is null
 ;
```

An `NOT EXISTS` version should work as well but I'm not sure that it would be very efficient, due to the double nesting:

```
select r.res_id, r.res_name
from Resource as r
where not exists
  ( select 1
    from
      ( select v.ran_resid
        from views as v
        order by v.viewsid
        limit 5
      ) as x
    where r.ran_resid = x.ran_resid
  ) ;
```

---

Also note that I removed the last `group by r.ran_resId` from your query.

It makes **no sense** to `group by a` and `select b, c` in a query. And while MySQL allows it, it is a guaranteed way to get garbage results.

Comment: 2 is not fixed actually it can be 5 or 10. It's 5 actually but for the sake of example i mentioned 2. Also the table on which I'm trying to compare has got 'n' number of data and I only need to compare last 5 records.

Comment: Two more methods added that should work with arbitrary limit.

Comment: The 2nd query you've posted **left join** is working fine however I'm unable to understand `where x.ran_resid is null`  this line, the query is working fine without this. need to test it with 4-5 more cases though.

Comment: No, without the `where x.ran_resid is null`, it's going to give you the opposite result.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot use limit in a subquery so you must use a left join with views table consist of two records you want to except on resid conditions then you pickup records that second table is null.